# What are the differences between "is", "does", and "has"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-meaning

> - The summer is not over.
> - The summer does not over.
> - The summer has not over.

What are the differences between using **is**, **does**, and **has** in these sentences? I've tried to find out but couldn't.

Comment: Hello, welcome to ELL. Did you look at the meanings of "is", "does", and "has" in any dictionary? What did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem lies with the ***adverb***  *over*. And according to  Cambridge Dictionary, **[be over](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/over)** is an *adjective*.

- We were so late that, when we got to the cinema, the film ***was over***.

If we look at a good online dictionary such as *[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/over)*, we see the following definition

> **over** adverb (FINISHED)
>
> B1 [level of difficulty]
>   (**especially of an event**) finished:
>
> - *I'll be glad when the competition **is** over.*
> - *I used to have a thriving business and a happy marriage, but that'**s** all over now*.

The [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)) verb *be* is necessary to connect  the subject (summer)  with "over"

1. Summer **is** over. (YES) [it is the end of summer]
   Summer **is not** over. (YES) [it is currently summer]
   Summer isn't over **yet**. (YES) [summer will end soon]

To use the other auxiliary verbs, *do* and *have*, you need a *verb* such as ***end***

2. Summer does not *over* (NO)
   It seems that summer **doesn't** ***end***. (YES) [Present Simple]
3. Summer has not over. (NO)
   Summer **has** not ***ended*** yet. (YES) [Present Perfect]

The important thing to remember from all this is that *over* is NOT a verb.

Answer (score 0):

- Is: Third person singular present of **be**.
- Does: Third person singular present of **do**.
- Has: Third person singular present of **have**

All three of them have different meanings.

> The summer is not over

is the only sentence that makes grammatical sense

> The summer does not **finish**

means that the summer does not end.

> The summer has not **finished**

means it's still summer.